# Prove that any power of a prime is not a perfect number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

How do I prove:

> Let $p$ be a prime, and $n$ be a positive integer.  Then $p^n$ is not a [perfect number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number).

One example is when $p = 2$ and $n = 3$, the question is to show $8$ is not a perfect number.  And I know that out of $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$, the proper divisors of $8$ are $1, 2,$ and $4$, with $1 + 2 + 4 = 7 \ne 8$, so $8$ is not a perfect number.

But how do I show this for *any* $n$ and $p$?

Comment: Can you list the factors of $p^n$? What's their sum?

Comment: If $p^n$ is a perfect number then $1+p+p^2+\cdots +p^n=2p^n$. Note that $p$ divides almost every term.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Does it therefore suffice to say that since $p$ divides the right side but not the left we have a contradiction QED?

Comment: Yes, I think it is enough. The fact that it does not divide the left side is I think obvious, indeed the left side is $\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: I edited to improve the question, but then I realized it's an exact duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502973/can-powers-of-primes-be-perfect-numbers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The divisors of $p^n$ are $1,p,p^2,\ldots,p^n$.  The *proper* divisors are all but the last one.  The sum of those is
$$
1+p+p^2+p^3+\cdots+p^{n-1}.
$$
This is a geometric series.  Apply the standard formula for the sum of a finite geometric series and see if you get $p^n$.

Comment: I'm still having some trouble understanding this. Perhaps can you go further?

Comment: Suppose one has $\text{sum}=1+p+p^2+p^3+p^4+p^5$. Then $p\times\text{sum}=p+p^2+p^3+p^4+p^5+p^6$.  Now subtract: $(p\times\text{sum}) - \text{sum}$.  All of the terms cancel except $p^6$ and $1$, so you get $p^6-1$.  But $(p\times\text{sum}) - \text{sum} = (p-1)\times\text{sum}$.  Consequently $(p-1)\times\text{sum}=p^6-1$, so $\text{sum}=\dfrac{p^6-1}{p-1}$.  The question is now whether that is equal to $p^6$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It isn't, right?

Comment: We don't need a formula for the sum of a GP. Note that $p$ divides every term except $1$, so if we have equality then $p$ must divide $1$, not true.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So basically if I write what you wrote in the comments for my actual question, then I should be fine?

Comment: @JoshuaMyers : Correct.  The sum cannot be divisible by $p$ unless the numerator is divisible by $p$, and the numerator differs by $1$ from something divisible by $p$. But the comment by André Nicolas also suffices. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'll give it to you though...Thanks to you and Andre

Comment: @JoshuaMyers: The solution of Michael Hardy exploits another frequently useful idea, note that $\frac{p^n-1}{p-1}$ is "too small."

Answer (score 3):

$p$ prime then, $1 +p + p^2 + \cdots + p^{n-1} \neq p^n$.